# Getting values of items in IList?

Tags: c#

Is there any way to get the values of items in the IList?
It goes like this:

Assume we have an `IList list` and a method `private IList getValues(int ID)`

then we initialize `IList list` like:

`IList list = getValues(SelectedID)`

After the processing, `IList list` now contains 2 elements, each with it's own collection:

```
[0]
 {
   GroupName = "test01"
   GroupID = 1
 }

[1]
 {
   GroupName = "test02"
   GroupID = 2
 }
```

How will I get the GroupName of the first element?
I can't just call it like `list[0].GroupName`, can I?

Comment: Unless you know the type of object, in the list, you would not be able to access properties unless you type cast, before accessing GroupName for example.

Comment: Why are you using non-generic `IList`?

Comment: @StephenBorg How will I do that? I'm new to this by the way.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek err... well, I don't know. I was tasked to edit the existing codes of the company so I'm just kinda testing it if it's gonna work or not.

Comment: Try to use IList<YourObject> instead IList

Comment: Why not declare   List<Group> list    instead of IList list?

Comment: @Frank59 IList<IList> list? Err. sorry. I currently don't know what I'm doinggg  >_<

Comment: @JohnJesus Okay I'll try that, wait a sec.

Comment: @Don I posted a code snippet accessing a list of custom objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following, you need to create a list with your custom object. I created a dummy class here named CustomClass, and creating a list with the known type.

```
public class CustomClass
    {
        public string GroupName { get; set; }
        public int GroupID { get; set; }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<CustomClass> list = new List<CustomClass>();
        foreach (var x in list) {
            Console.WriteLine(x.GroupName);
        }

    }
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. I came to this page by having an IList exposed from some api and I had to deal with it. I was expecting an answer on how to handle a non generic IList, not a generic one.

Answer (score 4):

If you know the type of the object,
you can use this to get what you want.

`list.Cast<Group>().ElementAt(0).GroupName`

Group as in your object name.